# Add Friends to Group on Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Ive looked through the API and dont see it, but I thought Id ask anyway. Can I add users to a group through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add users to a group via the API.